# Faster than numpy.matmul for multiplying matrix by its transpose

Tags: numpy, matrix, transpose, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I have a large 2D NumPy array M in python, and I want to compute `numpy.matmul(M, M.T)`, or equivalently, `numpy.dot(M, M.T)`.

However, `numpy.matmul` and `numpy.dot` won't exploit the symmetry involved in multiplication with the transpose, so I believe I am doing twice the work that I really need to do.

Is there an easy way to make this faster by exploiting the symmetry and only doing half the work? Perhaps there is a NumPy/SciPy function or some other python library I'm not aware of that accomplishes this?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786648/fast-multiplication-for-a-matrix-and-its-transpose) answer your question? Or [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02432390v4/document)?

Comment: @Ivan Thanks, but I should have clarified that I was wondering if there is some numpy library, or other python library, which I'm not aware of that does this, and exploits the fact that if A is the resulting product, then A[i][j] = A[j][i]

Comment: How do you know `matmul` does not exploit the symmetry?  Just the lack of explicit control parameters?  Have you done any time tests?

Comment: @hpaulj Ah I believe you're right, please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Someone informed me that numpy actually already accounts for the symmetry:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9a1229f86ca4d4041c9aa48027a21c7ad97da748/numpy/core/src/umath/matmul.c.src#L157